# Android String Comparison Not Working

Tags: android

I am having hard time comparing two strings in Android using Java, what I am doing is running HTTP get request which return yes or no and based on that I decide whether to launch a new activity or not.

I am performing the string comparison inside Async onPostExecute method and though the HTTP returned string is yes it is not working for me.

Here goes the code

```
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        if(result.equals("yes"))
        {
            Intent toDashboard = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,Dashboard.class); 
            startActivity(toDashboard);
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "It was yes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Though the returned string is yes it still skips the if statement and creates a toast showing "Yes".

I have also tried some other ways to match a string and they all goes here

```
if(result == "yes")
if(result.toString().equals("yes"))
if(result.contentEquals("yes"))
if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
```

None of them works for me

Comment: Try `result.equals("Yes")`

Comment: the first way you had it was correct, try making sure the logged `result` value doesn't have an extra space (`" "`) or something.

Comment: @AmanVirk : have you try `if(result.contains("yes"))` or after trimming result string as `if(result.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))` ?

Comment: Try result.trim() to remove whitespaces, newline etc.

Comment: Using trim() stops my application from running

Comment: Show us where you are returning the string

Comment: try Like this way if(result.compareTo("yes") ==0)  Or if(result.compareToIgnoreCase("yes") ==0)

Comment: Ok it worked for me with trim and my application was dying because of code running inside the if block.... Thanks to all

Answer (score 8):

There might be some white space in result.

Try trimming it.

```
result.trim().equals("yes")
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

**str1.toLowerCase().contains(str2.toLowerCase())**

it work for me